# Why isn't C's most basic printing function named `print` instead of `printf`?

Tags: programming-languages, c, terminology

AFAIK, C does not have a `print` function. The most basic we can get is `printf`. So, is there a reason why this function is not simply named `print`, instead of `printf`?

Note that [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122197/why-is-scanf-called-scanf-same-for-printf) question is about `scanf`/`readf` and `printf`/`writef`. This one is about `printf`/`print`.

Comment: Your premise that `printf` is C's most basic output function is [false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454474/what-is-the-difference-between-printf-and-puts-in-c). In addition to `puts`, there's also `putchar`.

Comment: The "f" at the end stands for "formatted," as in "print, formatted."  The extra extra letter is made up for by the fact that the `creat()` function has no "e" on the end.  :-)

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidHammen this is clearly not POB, there are historical reasons for it. Also, the dupe target explains why.

Comment: I have voted to reopen as (a) the question marked as duplicate is focussed on a different aspect of the naming decision and (b) while the answers there touch briefly on the question here they don't go into sufficient depth.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's go back to the K&R roots:

### Origin

In the tutorial chapter, on page 11 of original K&R, you'll find a hint on the origin of the function:

> By the way, `printf` is not part of the C language; there is no input
>   or output defined in C itself.  There is nothing magic about `printf`;
>   it's just a useful function that is part of **the standard library of
>   routines that are normally accessible to C programs**.

The wording "accessible" suggests that it could be based on libraries shared with other programming languages as suggested by Jules, or on shared OS libraries.  As B and C both are closely linked to the development of UNIX, and the same people, [D.Ritchie, B.W.Kernighan and K.Thompson](http://electronicdesign.com/dev-tools/thompson-ritchie-and-kernighan-fathers-c)  closely worked together on these matters, it is not surprising that they use similar naming conventions.

### Why the f of printf ?

The title of section ***7.3 Formatted output - printf*** on page 145 of original K&R strongly suggest that the `f` stands for formatted:

Searching in other sources will show that B's and C's `printf` [both seem to originate from BCPL's `writef` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#1960s:_BCPL.2C_ALGOL_68.2C_Multics_PL.2FI) which used already in 1966 the `%` formatting character.

Also worth to note that Algol68 also adopted  `printf` function for formatted output.  Yet the formatting logic was a little different.

Answer (score 20):

The function "printf" was inherited by C from the B standard library. In B it wasn't the only such function, for example there was also a "printn" for printing numbers. See a reference for the language from an early unix version here: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.html

Answer (score 7):

**It's not the most basic printing function.** The most basic printing functions would be `puts` and `putchar` which print a string and char respectively.

**f is for formatted.** `printf` (unlike `puts` or `putchar`) prints *formatted* output, hence print**f**. For example it can print an int in hexadecimal, or a float rounded to three decimal places, or a string left padded. (Yep, you read that right: **in the 1970s** C had a single string function in the standard library doing more than [an entire npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad). ;)

**C didn't do `printf` first.** B has a function of the same name with similar functionality. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#1960s:_BCPL.2C_ALGOL_68.2C_Multics_PL.2FI) identifies an even earlier inspiration in BCPL's `writef`.